# Can't browse to website running in Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running a simple api that connects to mongodb
I have two containers and am creating them using the following docker-compose file. I was expecting to then be able to browse to localhost:3000 but there's nothing there.  I've also tried getting the IP of the container and browsing to IP:3000 too, but this doesn't work either.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  fitch-api:
    image: MyACR.azurecr.io/test-api
    restart: always
    links: [ mongo ]
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: db-cms-test
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Answer (score 0):

I think port 3000 not openning inside docker. Let's check by

```
docker exec -ti container_name ss -ntpl
```

Or check logs of docker instance by

```
docker logs container_name
```

Comment: running the logs just shows the console output as the app boots up and it seems to be fine.

Comment: the second command gives me the is:
State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port              
LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.11:42665                    *:*                  
LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.1:3000                     *:*                   users:(("node",pid=78,fd=22))

Comment: your app should listen  0.0.0.0 for external access.for example 
```server.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', onListening);
```